# How to display duplicates from a text file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, file, awk, words

I'm trying to find out how to use the "awk" command, in order to display a word that shows up multiple times in a file(txt). In addition, how can you display the name of this/those file/s?

ex: first sentence first file.
    Second sentence followed by the second word.

This should display: "first" and "second"

Comment: Why `first`? it doesn't show up _multiple times_. Please make a proper example and expected output. _with -i_ , what do you mean?

Comment: I have changed it, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume with `-i` you mean comparison / counting should be ignoring case.

If I understand your requirements correctly an command like this should work:

```
awk '{ for( i=1; i<=NF; i++){ cnt[ tolower( $i ) ]++; if (cnt[$i] > 1) {print $i} } }' yourfile | sort -u
```

It prints these words for your example:

- first
- second
- sentence
- the

If you need a case sensitive counting, just delete `tolower` .

For each line in the file, the script iterates through each word (the `for( i=1 i <= NF; i++)` loop):

- increments for each word a counter ( `cnt[ tolower( $i) ]++` )
- if the count is larger than 1 the word is printer
- the pipe to `sort -u` sorts the output and removes the duplicates from the output.